# Regex syntax to check prefixes and suffixes

Tags: java, regex, sigasi-studio

I'm building some regex expressions to match naming conventions in Sigasi Studio (which uses Java syntax for regex). For example, a port name must end in _i or _o - e.g. my_input_port_i

I tried using the txt2re generator, however instead of a simple expression it [generated code](http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3?s=my_input_port_i&-20&-22).

Looking at regex syntax, it seems that the "$" character (end of line) and the "|" symbol (OR) could be helpful - something like `$_i|_o` but after testing with regex101.com no matches are found.

Naming convention dialog:

[image: Sigasi Studio Naming Conventions]

Comment: you are searching for end-of-line (end_of_text) **followed** by "_i"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sigasi Studio the entire name should match. So your are looking for:

```
.*_[io]
```

Comment: That works! Thanks for the Sigasi-specific advice. From this, I figure that prefixes are similar, for example to test if something starts with _u or  _i you can do: 

[u|i]_.*

Answer (score 2):

The `$` means end of the string, but you use it at the beginning.

Maybe you are looking for this at the end of the string, which uses an underscore `_`, then a character class to match `i` or `o` and then matches the end of the string `$`

[`_[io]$`](https://regex101.com/r/B0W5wK/1/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was unaware that the "$" had to be at the end, my presumption was that the pseudocode of the syntax was:

"at the end of the line, search for _i or _o"

whereas it's actually

"search for _i or _o then end of line"